# How to use a Python lab machine as server to my C++ client code?

Tags: python, c++, rest, ipc, remote-server

I have a powerful lab machine with special Python code on it for doing image segmentation. On it, I can do something like:

```
$ run_segmentation.py image.png result.png
# that's a 40 second operation on 100MB input to produce 500MB output.
```

I need to execute this from my desktop from the other side of the building. I'm writing a C++ application that uses the result.png to do further processing.

Comment: Interesting. Do you also have a question that is suitable for SO?

Comment: Walkie talkies and grad students.

Comment: @erip Nah, [IPoAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers).

Comment: How to distribute a computation over 2 machines isn't an SO suitable question. I'm sorry, is this your answer to a serious problem with not a single tutorial online to address?

Comment: 1. Your "question" does not contain an actual question (much less one that adheres to the guidelines). 2. You are not trying to distribute computation (according to your description), you just want to execute some code remotely 3. SO is not a tutorial site, so that argument is completely irrelevant

Comment: @Sqandr: One of the fundamental skills in programming is to break down a problem in smaller subproblems. Another is to consider how you'd solve the problem manually. (Obviously these overlap). We don't see evidence of either.

Comment: Thanks @MSalters, I see your point. It's my fault--I purposefully wanted to ask a higher-level question that didn't give too much guide to the solution. I am working on a solution that uses sockets, however that's being challenging and I asked specific help there too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46615493/python-socket-programming-design-and-implementation-send-file-to-server-server

Answer (score 1):

You could transfer `image.png` to the remote machine using a unix tool such as `scp` or `rsync`, use an ssh shell to invoke the command and then copy `result.png` back to your desktop for processing with your C++ application.

Comment: This assumes an Unix OS running on the lab machine... And an SSH server running, of course.